# Change Is Identity to yes on existing column

Tags: sql-server, ssms, identity, ddl, alter-table

In SSMS on my development DB, I set `IsIdentity` to true on an `int` field, and after a short wait the changes complete and all seems to work.  The column is currently populated with values that cannot change.

On production however, with ~1mm rows, SSMS seems to freeze and not apply the change successfully.

Adding a new column, dropping the old one, renaming them etc isn't an option as there are too many relationships.

Often I find on the production DB, running the query explicitly as supposed to using the SSMS interface does seem to work a lot better.

Is there a simple alter query that will change the `IsIdentity` to true?

Comment: "*Adding a new column, ... isn't an option*" - I think that's precisely what SSMS does in the background

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name understood, is there a way to get the scripts it's running before it runs them so I can execute them myself in the new query window instead of the table editor?  (For some reason, this seems to be 100x quicker for longer running scripts)

Comment: You can view the script that SSMS would execute, review it and execute it yourself. Sometimes it can be over-cautious with a table rebuild and an `alter table` can suffice, it depends.

Comment: `with ~1mm rows, SSMS seems to freeze` it doesn't freeze. This process is slow. It has to modify every single row and add a new value. SSMS is overly cautious though, and creates a *copy* of the table with the changes, moving all changes over, then swaps the old and new table. You may be able to add a new column and then rename the columns, change keys and indexes, to replace the old column with the new one

Comment: You should always and only make changes to a production system using scripts IMO - a task that should begin with a backup. It also seems that adding the identity property to an existing column a production table should involve much more work since the applications that manipulate that table need to be tested (and likely updated) to reflect this change.

Comment: For large tables it is easier to do it as a metadata only change with `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`  - though million rows isn't really that large unless columns are very wide or running on a limited  SKU

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos looks frozen to me, it whites out and becomes unresponsive.  No way to know if it's still doing work or not.  Same thing happens when generating change scripts, it appears I have no current way of making this change in production!

Comment: Having to resort to `ID = db.Users.OrderByDescending(c=> c.ID).First().ID + 1` for now, which isn't ideal.